# Cannot deploy project to another server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I develop MFP app using MFP Studio 7.1. However, when I want to build for UAT server, I can't.

I have tried to change the server value inside `worklight.properties` inside `server>conf` folder to my appropriate server URL:

```
publicWorkLightHostname=some.ip.address
# HTTP or HTTPS
publicWorkLightProtocol=http
# For default port leave empty
publicWorkLightPort=10080
```

I do "Build Settings and Deploy Target" but nothing happens as well as my Worklight server. Do I lack of something?

Comment: What does it mean when you say you want to build , but you can't ?
Is the .war file not getting generated ? Are you not able to deploy the war file to your UAT server using ANT or ServerConfigTool?
As for , "Build Settings and Deploy target" , if you use that before generating your artifacts - .wlapp, does it not get generated with the right settings?

Comment: Put my comment under Idan :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right. MobileFirst Studio only deploys to the locally running server within the Studio. It is an integrated development environment, not a "deployment service".

However, the studio can *prepare* the project to connect to a different server.
For this you need to select **Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target** ([see documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html)). There you set the server details, and upon the next build that you will perform, those settings will be embedded in the application instead of the local server details.

You then need to use tools such as Ant or any other tool you want in order to deploy the .wlapp and .adapter files. The generated project itself you continue to build in Xcode/Android Studio/Visual Studio, and that project - as mentioned - will be already set to connect to the remote server.

You can, however, use the MobileFirst 7.1 CLI which has the option to define multiple servers, local or remote, and you can then use the "mfp push" command to deploy to remote servers.

Comment: I see. I thought that in MFP Studio can deploy to remote server too, but it only creates the configuration for all environment projects, then I need to deploy it myself. In conclusion, MFP Studio is for until building files of app and adapters, then it's up to me. Am i correct?